# Drop Down List on change no trigger

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="sandbox">
<p>
    <label> Answer Type</label>
    <select name="ans_type[]">
        <option value="Image">Image</option>
        <option value="Text">Text</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p class="text">
    <label> Enter Answer</label>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="ans_text[]"></textarea>
</p>
<p class="image">
    <label> Upload Image</label> <br/>
    <input type="file" name="ans_image[]" class="btn"/>
</p>
<p>
    <label> Is Correct Answer</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="isCorrectAnswer[]"/>
</p>
```

JS

```
$('#addButton').click(function() {
        var newHTML = "";
        newHTML += '<p><label> Answer Type</label><select name="ans_type[]"><option value="Image">Image</option><option value="Text">Text</option></select></p><p><label> Enter Answer</label><textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="ans_text[]"></textarea></p><p><label> Upload Image</label> <br/><input type="file" name="ans_image[]" class="btn"/></p>';
        $('#sandbox').html($('#sandbox').html() + newHTML);
    });
    $("input[name*='ans_type']").change(function() {
        alert("asd");
        var answer = $(this).val();
        if (answer == "Image") {
            $(".text").hide();
            $(".image").show();
        } else {
            $(".text").show();
            $(".image").hide();
        }
    });
```

When I select the drop down list of ans_type the change function doesn't trigger. The problem should be lay on input[name*='ans_type'] <-- because when user click Add button, will duplicate the input so how should I change this to make the effect available for all ans_type[] drop down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's should be `$("select[name*='ans_type']")` instead of `$("input[name*='ans_type']")` since you target `select` not `input` element

You can also use event delegation for dynamically added element:

```
$(document).on("change","select[name*='ans_type']", function(){
    alert("asd");
    var text = $(this).closest('#sandbox').find('.text'),
        image = $(this).closest('#sandbox').find('.image'),
        answer = $(this).val();
    if (answer == "Image") {
        text.hide();
        image.show();
    } else {
        text.show();
        image.hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, my code now if one change to text all others answer will change to text as well and vise versa, how can I modify so that when I select this particular answer to format text only current one will change other remains.

Comment: @user236501 See my updated answer, you need to replace `$(".text").hide();`, `$(".text").show();` to make sure you target the correct text. Do the same for image as well.

Comment: Yaya I understand, my question is when I add the ans_type select, input text field will duplicate one more, as you can see the name I save as []. I put the <p class="text" so when user select image text will be hide. This work fine. But when I got 2 and more, if I select text it will affect other to change to text as well

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("select[name*='ans_type']")
```